# How to check in Eclipse if a particular library is in Java build path?

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

Sometimes I want to check if a particular JAR is in build path by right-clicking on the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries

So here is the list I need but i miss a way to search a particular library by name like Ctrl+F. I have to look the whole (unsorted!) list of hundreds of JARs instead. Is there a more comfortable way? I couldn't find one so far.

Comment: If you have hundreds of JARs, you probably use Maven or Gradle, right?  If it is Maven, you can do search/filter in the POM editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you including the libraries in your project? If you are using Maven, then open the "pom.xml" file and click on the tab "Dependency Hierarchy" at the bottom of the editor view. There then will be a tree of all libraries (dependencies) used with a "filter" input at the top of the view.

If you are using Gradle, then there may be a similar way, but I'm not familiar with the Gradle plugin for Eclipse.

If you aren't using any dependency management tool such as Maven or Gradle, but are adding all the JARs manually, then all I would recommend switching to one, because they have many other advantages, too.